# Why the deboarding in Bangkok on flight BR61 (Taipei → Bangkok → Vienna)?

Tags: air-travel, airports, airport-security, bangkok

I recently flew from Taipei (TPE) to Vienna (VIE) via Bangkok (BKK), with EVA Air BR61.

In Bangkok, all passengers had to deboard, and then go through security again and board again, for a ~1 hour stop.

That was quite inconvenient (and sleep-interrupting). What's the reason behind this? Safety considerations during refueling?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fact that you had to go through security indicates a change in security rules between regions. This is since airlines have to follow certain norms for flights entering different regions, in this case Europe. This happened to my while flying Canada to Europe via Iceland where we got off, passed security and got back on.

Even if you were not changing regions, you might have had to deplane and reboard again. This happens because the crew will also clean the plane, refill service items and ensure that no one that got off at that stop left something on board which could be a security risk.  I've had a flight that refueled in Alaska where we all had to got off and reboard but not pass security.

There are cases where neither passing security or disembarking are required too, although I have not seen this happen in years.

Comment: Did that flight that stopped in Alaska originate in the continental U.S.?

Comment: Not sure about the whole region thing applying here, EVA operates a direct connection between Taipei and Vienna, too.

Comment: In that case you would have done the European security protocol in Taipei but given that some people were probably flying to Bangkok only, they had to do the right security measures for Thailand. Yes, I know, the measures are virtually the same but they have to do it again by regulation. I asked exactly that question from the agent when doing the security hop out-and-back-in in Iceland.